# Occasional freezing when playing RTSP video using OpenCV + Gstreamer

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I play an rtsp video of a person walking by with Gtreamer.
But it plays the video with occasional pauses. So missed some frames.

```
    gst = f'rtspsrc location={url}  latency=3000 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=10 sync=false' 

    with g_gst_lock:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

How do I fix it. I want to make sure there are no missed frames.

Comment: did you try setting the max_buffers parameter to a higher value ? If so, do you still experience missing frames ?

Comment: Does this help `gst = f'gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc  ....`

Comment: @toyotaSupra Thank you. But it didn't help.

Comment: @Toyo Thank you. But it didn't help.